Tracing binding redirects in app.config that was added by Visual Studio
I have a solution with about 10 projects, mostly dll. I updated a NuGet package, CSVHelper to a new version. Visual Studio then added app.config files with binding redirects to several of my projects, and because it did so silently, they did not get added to source control, which caused our build server to fail because the app.config files are referenced in the csproj files.
I'm trying to figure out why the binding redirects are needed, but finding it impossible to track it down. For example, one of the binding redirects is for System.Tuple, which Visual Studio added a Binding Redirect to version 4.0.3.0. When I look at the references for that project, System.ValueTuple is not listed.
In addition, the version of the package updated, CSVHelper, shows that it needs System.ValueTuple >= 4.3.0, so I'm not sure why the Binding Redirect for the project that doesn't reference CSVHelper is pointing to 4.0.3.0.
How do you figure out why VS added the app.config file with a binding redirect to 4.0.3.0?
In the general case, how do you track down why VS (or Nu Get) adds app.config files with binding redirects, and where the dependancies are coming from?

Are these ten projects related to each other?

@BowmanZhu - Yes, all related projects. A console, a windows service, and a bunch of libraries shared by both.

Binding redirection is a thing used to keep dependencies consistent.
Generally, Suppose you have application A that references library B, and also library C of version  4.0.3.0. Library B in turn also references library C, but of version 4.3.0. But you cannot load different versions of the same assembly at runtime, that's the reason.
To resolve this conflict you can use binding redirect, usually to the new version (but can be to the old too).

Thanks. I understand what the binding redirect is for, but I’m trying to figure out why it was added. For instance, if VS adds binding redirect for a specific library, I want to know which library (or libraries) referenced the one that the binding redirect was added for. For instance if system.tuple has a binding redirect, I want to know which libraries reference which versions because I might just upgrade the libraries so they have matching references.
